# Arduino TimerOne breaks the program when calling "digitalRead"

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, rfid

I'm trying to make [this](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DIYRFIDReader) project.

But i have a problem running this code. It appears to be `val = digitalRead(inPin);` breaks entire program. just because i call this from the `callback` function which attached as an interrupt function `Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);`

Here is the more simplified problem simulation program,

```
#include "TimerOne.h"

int inPin = 7;   // sensing digital pin 7

int val;

void setup() {
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);      // sets the digital pin 7 as input to sense receiver input signal

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Timer1.initialize(8);  // initialize timer1, and set the frequency; this drives both the LC tank as well as the pulse timing clock
  // note: modify this as needed to achieve resonance and good match with the desired tags
  // the argument value is in microseconds per RF cycle, so 8us will yield RF of 125kHz, 7us --> 143kHz, etc.

  Timer1.pwm(9, 512);

  Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);
}

void callback()
{
  val = digitalRead(inPin);//once you comment this line, it works fine
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Program running \n");

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I give you +1 point for taking care of reducing your code to the minimum that show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time between 2 interrupt triggers is only 8us. Also `digitalRead()` is a quite big function, that needs some time to execute (I don't know how much). That way it is to short for the Serial print command to execute in the leftover time. Make the following change and you will see, that it works.

```c
void loop(){
  noInterrupts();
  Serial.print("Program running \n");
  interrupts();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Now the interrupts are disabled during the execution of the `Serial.print()`, so that it can finish. After this the interrupts are enabled again and we wait for 1 second to give the interrupts some time before we are disabling them again.

The speed of the Arduino is limited, so you cannot do much, when constantly triggering interrupts in the pace of 8us. If you only want to check this digital input you can get the value directly with using the PINB registers (refer to [this side](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation)), which works much faster.

Also you should consider making the variable `val` volatile, since it will can change everytime through your interrupt service routine.

Comment: Thanks mate, It all makes sense. And i'll try this out and let you know how it went. Still i wonder how the tutorial worked for them at some point, Perhaps it was an older Arduino core?

Comment: I'm not sure about how the tutorial worked for them. On a quick look I see, that they are not sending serial in every loop cycle, but only when special conditions arrive. Not sure about how this changes the problem. To be sure you would have to measure the length of the interrupt routine with an oszilloscope